# Function return multiple value

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters, arguments

I have this modified code here, how do I pass the argument?

```
function RNG(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function RCG() {
  var char = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
  var randomNumber = RNG(0, char.length - 1);

  return char[randomNumber];
}

function Generator(n) {
  var serialNumber;
  var template = "0000-0000-0000-0000";

  if (template != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < template.length; i++) {
      var templateChar = template[i];
      serialNumber += templateChar == "0" ? RCG() : templateChar;
    }
  }

  return serialNumber;
}

console.log(Generator(5));
```

So when I enter 3 as the argument, the result will be like:

```
asda-asda-asda-asda
asda-asda-asda-asda
asda-asda-asda-asda
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are asking is to be able to return 5 of these UUID from your method?

I have modified your Generator to return an array of UUIDs

```
function Generator(n) {
  var template = "0000-0000-0000-0000";
  var res = []; // declare an empty array
  if (template != null) {
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++){
        var serialNumber = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < template.length; i++) {
          var templateChar = template[i];
          serialNumber += templateChar == "0" ? RCG() : templateChar;
        }
        res.push(serialNumber); // add uuid in the array
    }
  }

  return res; // return the array
}
```

Output:

```
["1MYK-G2BB-YPG4-UYHU", "PWW1-6297-2VJX-56F2", "5U5B-A40D-9V43-WC6Y", "FQHQ-BU6A-CDS8-Y2J7", "23WK-1ASP-YA5Z-TS0R"]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was cool! Better than I imagine.

I also make some alternate change, but somehow the last 2 line got duplicate.
I'll try to fix it later and keep your code as a reference. Once again, thank you! :D